# I'm trying to install the Arabic data on Tesseract, but when I do, it gives me this:

Tags: homebrew, tesseract, arabic

I'm trying to install the Arabic data on Tesseract using Terminal using this command. I have homebrew installed

brew install tesseract-ocr-[ara]

But I keep getting this error. 
Any thoughts?

Error: No available formula with the name "tesseract-ocr-[ara]" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

It suggested that I do a deeper clone since I had only done a shallow clone, so I did that, but it still gave me this same result.

Comment: Are you sure that package should exist? Usually names don’t have angle brackets in them at least

Comment: This is what I've seen suggested online before. It could have been a training package. Do you know what I can do to get the language itself installed on Tesseract?

Comment: You can simply download required language from their github https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata (this is for tesseract 4 and higher, change branch for lower versions) and put it alongside your other languages (or you can also specify path to the directory with tessdata when you run tesseract - `tesseract --tessdata-dir /path/to/myfolder`)

Answer (score 2):

`brew info tesseract` says:

```
tesseract: stable 4.1.0 (bottled), HEAD
OCR (Optical Character Recognition) engine
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/tesseract.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: autoconf, autoconf-archive, automake, libtool, pkg-config
Required: leptonica, libtiff
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
This formula contains only the "eng", "osd", and "snum" language data files.
If you need all the other supported languages, `brew install tesseract-lang`.
```

This suggests that you need to run `brew install tesseract-lang`.

Comment: this will install all languages not just Arabic?